# Cycle Detection in a Graph with Arbitrary Vertex Numbers

Tags: python, graph, cycle

I'm currently working on a small project that takes a series of pairs of documents numbered from 1 to N and topologically sorts them.
I have completed the topological sorting algorithm but I am having trouble putting together a working cycle detection that will work with arbitrary vertex numbers.

My graph class is defined as such:

```
class Graph: 
def __init__(self): 
    self.graph = defaultdict(list) #Dicionário
    self.size = 0

def add_edge(self,u ,v): 
    self.graph[u].append(v) #Adicionar 
    
def get_size(self):
    for u in self.graph:
        for v in self.graph[u]:
            self.size = self.size + 1

def topological_sort(self) -> list: 
    visitado = set()
    inverso = list() 
    vertices = set(self.graph.keys())
    for vertex in vertices: 
        if vertex not in visitado:
            self._topological_sort_auxiliar(vertex, visitado, inverso)
        return list(reversed(inverso))

def _topological_sort_auxiliar(self, vertex, visitado, inverso): 
    visitado.add(vertex)
    for adj_vertex in self.graph[vertex]: 
        if adj_vertex not in visitado: 
            self._topological_sort_auxiliar(adj_vertex, visitado, inverso) 
    inverso.append(vertex)
```

And these are the two functions causing trouble:

```
 def DFS(self, u, color): 
    color[u] = "CINZA"
    for v in self.graph[u]:
        if color[v] == "CINZA":
            return True
        if color[v] == "BRANCO" and self.DFS(v, color) == True:
            return True
    color[u] = "PRETO"
    return False

def isCyclic(self):
    vertices = set(self.graph.keys())
    print(vertices)
    color = ["BRANCO"] * len(vertices)
    print(color)
    for i in range(len(vertices)):
        if color[i] == "BRANCO":
            if self.DFS(i, color) == True:
                return True
    return False
```

For example, when I run **isCyclic** on a graph with [(1,2),(2,1),(2,3),(3,4)], this is the **Traceback**:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-828e210e0189> in <module>
----> 1 if G.isCyclic() == True:
      2     print("Informação Incoerente")
      3 else:
      4     sorted_list = G.topological_sort()
      5     print("Lista de documentos ordenada:")

<ipython-input-2-8081bbad75e6> in isCyclic(self)
     45         for i in range(len(vertices)):
     46             if color[i] == "BRANCO":
---> 47                 if self.DFS(i, color) == True:
     48                     return True
     49         return False

<ipython-input-2-8081bbad75e6> in DFS(self, u, color)
     33             if color[v] == "CINZA":
     34                 return True
---> 35             if color[v] == "BRANCO" and self.DFS(v, color) == True:
     36                 return True
     37         color[u] = "PRETO"

<ipython-input-2-8081bbad75e6> in DFS(self, u, color)
     31         color[u] = "CINZA"
     32         for v in self.graph[u]:
---> 33             if color[v] == "CINZA":
     34                 return True
     35             if color[v] == "BRANCO" and self.DFS(v, color) == True:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What suggestions or changes could I apply in order to allow a cycle search on a graph like this?

Comment: How does `color` look like when you produce the error (how many elements does it have): List indexing starts with `0` and your nodes start with `1` -- that might be an issue?

Comment: Color has only 4 elements, it should contain 5, however. I've noticed the issue might be just that, I just can't get a good fix for it.